# jQuery each loop not incrementing on safari

Tags: jquery, safari, each

My issue relates to the Safari browser only.

I have a grid with 28 columns. The first column contains names, while the remaining 27 each represent a week for the first 6 months of the year with seven small columns inside each representing the day of the week. 
Each row represents a person and the grid highlights what days people are working or on vacation (i.e. Vacation Calendar).

I am using jQuery to loop through the grid and calculate the number of small columns (i.e. day of the week) which contain a specific class name which identifies if a person in on vacation. At the bottom of the grid, I append a total for every day, showing how many people are working that particular day. The each loop loops vertically down the column of the first day of every person and adds that to an array (i.e [5,0,0,0,0]) and repeats for the other 4 day in the weekday (i.e. [5,4,5,5,0] before moving to the next week column and repeating the process. It is an array of 5 as I don't calculate the weekend. I end up with 27 arrays. Then I go into another each loop and append the values of the array for every day which are the totals.

```
function CalculateTotalWorkersPerDay_Name() {
//Count number of month columns which contains the weeks
var tdCount = $(".halfYear .outertr:nth-child(2) td.outer").length;
var sum = 0;
var count;
var toolTipContent;

//iterate based on the amount of date columns
for (count = 0; count < tdCount; count++) {
    var totals = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

    function getTotals() {
        var tdNum = count + 2; //represents 2nd child as the first is the name fíeld
        //iterate over every direct tr
        $(".halfYear tr.outertr").each(function () {
            $(this).find(".outer:nth-child(" + tdNum + ") .inner tr td").each(function (j) {
                if ($(this).hasClass("std") || $(this).hasClass("other")) {
                    sum += 1;
                    totals[j] += 1;
                }
            });
        });
        //Insert total values into html
        $(".totalRow td.outer:nth-child(" + tdNum + ") td.totalSum").each(function (k) {

            toolTipContent = util.tr("Mon: " + totals[0] + "</br>Tues: " + totals[1] + "</br>Wed: " + totals[2] + "</br>Thurs: " + totals[3] + "</br>Fri: " + totals[4],
                "Mo: " + totals[0] + "</br>Di: " + totals[1] + "</br>Mi: " + totals[2] + "</br>Do: " + totals[3] + "</br>Fr: " + totals[4], "");

            var splitNum = ("" + totals[k]).split("");
            if (totals[k] != null) {
                if (totals[k].toString().length == 2) {
                    $(this).append("<span style='display:block;'>" + splitNum[0] + "</span><span>" + splitNum[1] + "</span>");
                }
                else if (totals[k].toString().length == 3) {
                    $(this).append("<span style='display:block;'>" + splitNum[0] + "</span><span style='display:block;'>" + splitNum[1] + "</span><span>" + splitNum[2] + "</span>");
                }
                else {
                    $(this).append("<span style='display:block;'>" + totals[k] + "</span>");
                }
            }
            $(".totalSumTable" + count + " ").attr("onmouseover", "Tip('" + toolTipContent + "', OFFSETY, 20)");
            $(".totalSumTable" + count + " ").attr("onmouseout", "UnTip()");
        });
        console.log(totals);
    }
    getTotals(count);
};
```

}

The method works except with the safari browser and I d'on't know why. In safari I still get 27 arrays but only the first array (i.e. [0,8,8,8,7]) correctly shows the total. If somebody could explain if it is an issue with my code or an issue with Safari that would be great and of course, I can provide more information when requested. I hope my code and problem are clear enough at this point as I really don't what the issue is apart from the each looping.

The numbers in the images are shown vertically due to space restrictions (i.e. 11 is 1 under 1).

[image: Chrome: working]

[image: Safari: not working]

**Update:** If I run the function a second time in the console, it shows the correct data. When I debug the code, it gives the correct data too. Maybe it has to do with when the function is called.

**Update 2:** In the each loop below the comment "Insert total values into html", the k variable is not incrementing which results in only the first index value in the totals array being appended in each total.

Comment: Okay. So what debugging have you done? Safari has a built-in debugger you can use to step through the code, check the values of variables, follow the logic...

Comment: I am currently debugging, but I wanted to find out is there an obvious reason that it doesn't work with Safari that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was how I was selecting element for the each function. I broke it down and that fixed the iteration of the each loop. It now works on all browsers. The difficulty with this issue was when I debugged the code in the browser, it worked fine.

**OLD**

```
$(".halfYear tr.outertr").each(function () {
            $(this).find(".outer:nth-child(" + tdNum + ") .inner tr td").each(function (j) {
            $(this).find(".inner tr td").each(function (j) {
                if ($(this).hasClass("std") || $(this).hasClass("other")) {
                    totals[j] += 1;
                }
            });
        });
```

**UPDATED**

```
$(".halfYear tr.outertr .outer:nth-child(" + tdNum + ")").each(function () {
            //added below line
            $(this).find(".inner tr td").each(function (j) {
                if ($(this).hasClass("std") || $(this).hasClass("other")) {
                    totals[j] += 1;
                }
            });
        });
```